# Can't specify controller for Ember View

Tags: ember.js

I am defining a controller like so:

```
App.LessonEnterController = Ember.Controller.extend({ /* logic */ });
```

A View like so:

```
App.LessonEnterView = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set("controller", App.LessonEnterController.create());
    }
});
```

I found that workaround on [this github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1712), but I also tried:

```
App.LessonEnterView = Ember.View.extend({
    controller: App.LessonEnterController.create()
    // also: controller: Ember.Controller.extend({ /* logic */ })
});
```

I'm using it in a template like so:

```
{{#view App.LessonEnterView}}
    {{currentDaysAgo}} // Defined as currentDaysAgo: 0 in controller.
{{/view}}
```

Here's the error message I'm getting when it tries to render that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'has' of null
```

and it doesn't render anything at all. Help?

**Edit** Here's a pastebin of the [complete `LessonEnterController`](http://pastebin.com/R9Ugr5CB). It's doing quite a few things.

Comment: will you show what currentDaysAgo does?

Comment: Edited one of my comments to show this.

Comment: Also just added a pastebin showing the complete controller

Comment: Changing the controller to type `ObjectController` doesn't help either.

Comment: try removing `this.set("controller", App.LessonEnterController.create());` from your view `init()`. controller-route-template-view bindings are automagic! you should not have to specify it in your view declaration

Comment: though if the above handles your problem... I would still wonder why reassigning would break the magic?

Comment: If that line is removed, then the view will inherit the parentView's context instead of having it's own, and simply passing the controller in as a property doesn't work either.

Comment: controllers aren't generated for views

Comment: I'm trying to get behavior like in "view context" section of this page: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html but I'm adding the view in a template rather than programatically.

Comment: ok I get it, this is a subController, then you could access it with `controller.subcontroller.currentDaysAgo` if you `needs` it on the parent controller. no? @kingpin2k?

Comment: The point is that this view needs to have it's own actions and attributes, but have the option to access parent attributes as well. That's what the `needs` line shown in my pastebin is for.

Comment: then maybe you could use the render helper. http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper

Comment: Hmm, yeah if I used `render` and didn't pass it a model that could work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scope of the view you need to reference the controller

```
{{#view App.LessonEnterView}}
    {{controller.currentDaysAgo}} // Defined as currentDaysAgo: 0 in controller.
{{/view}}
```

Unfortunately, when you manually create a controller the container won't hook up all of the niceties. like the needs.  I'd recommend render (if block isn't necessary) or render then block

Comment: Yeah your code didn't create any change. I'm going to try render.

Comment: It's failing when it tries to resolve your needs.  It doesn't have the container for reference

Comment: Yeah I had a little mistake and now that code *does* work, but yeah without the nice stuff also supported I'm definitely going to use render.